# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x12

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am just getting the below error: How can i fix this?

I have "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x12". i check all the solution in stack overflow but nothing solved this issue.is this because version problem or anything else.Please help!
Thankyou

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/card_background"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:background="@drawable/comment_background"
android:stateListAnimator="@anim/comment_selection"
android:clickable="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/hints"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_status"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_app_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@+id/iv_status"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="@string/btn_login"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hints"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_label_priority"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/client" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_priority"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_label_priority"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/iv_label_priority"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_label_priority"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="@string/btn_login"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_label_date"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/iv_label_priority"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/client" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_label_date"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/iv_label_date"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_label_date"
            android:lines="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/btn_login"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_label_assign"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/iv_label_date"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/client" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_assign"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_label_assign"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/iv_label_assign"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_label_assign"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="@string/btn_login"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_label_task"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/iv_label_assign"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/client" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_task"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/iv_label_task"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_label_task"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="@string/btn_login"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_label_client"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/iv_label_task"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/client" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_client"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_label_client"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/iv_label_client"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_label_client"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="@string/btn_login"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_label_time"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv_date"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_date"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_date"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/client" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_label_time"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/iv_label_time"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_label_time"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="@string/btn_login"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color" />

    </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_login"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_login"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_login"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_login"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_login"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Adapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.transition.TransitionManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import bd.com.rtchubs.taskapp.R;
import bd.com.rtchubs.taskapp.admin_model.AdminProjects;

public class AdminProjectsListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdminProjectsListAdapter.AdminProjectsListViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<AdminProjects> projectsList;
private int mExpandedPosition = -1;
private View itemView;

public AdminProjectsListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<AdminProjects> projectsList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.projectsList = projectsList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public AdminProjectsListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.admin_fragment1_individual_view, viewGroup, false);
    return new AdminProjectsListViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final AdminProjectsListViewHolder adminProjectsListViewHolder, final int i) {

    final boolean isExpanded = i == mExpandedPosition;
    adminProjectsListViewHolder.details.setVisibility(isExpanded?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
    adminProjectsListViewHolder.itemView.setActivated(isExpanded);
    adminProjectsListViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mExpandedPosition = isExpanded ? -1:i;
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) itemView);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    AdminProjects projects = projectsList.get(i);

    adminProjectsListViewHolder.tv_title.setText(projects.getProjectsName());
    adminProjectsListViewHolder.tv_priority.setText(projects.getProjectsPriority());
    adminProjectsListViewHolder.tv_date.setText(projects.getProjectsDate());
    adminProjectsListViewHolder.tv_time.setText(projects.getProjectsTime());
    adminProjectsListViewHolder.tv_task.setText(projects.getProjectsTask());
    adminProjectsListViewHolder.tv_assign.setText(projects.getProjectsAssign());
    adminProjectsListViewHolder.tv_client.setText(projects.getProjectsClient());

    if(projects.getProjectsPriority() == 1){
        adminProjectsListViewHolder.iv_status.setImageResource(R.drawable.done);
    } else if(projects.getProjectsPriority() == 2){
        adminProjectsListViewHolder.iv_status.setImageResource(R.drawable.progress);
    } else if(projects.getProjectsPriority() == 3){
        adminProjectsListViewHolder.iv_status.setImageResource(R.drawable.pending);
    } else if(projects.getProjectsPriority() == 4){
        adminProjectsListViewHolder.iv_status.setImageResource(R.drawable.due);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return projectsList.size();
}

public class AdminProjectsListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView tv_title,tv_priority,tv_date,tv_assign,tv_task,tv_client,tv_time;
    public ImageView iv_status;
    public RelativeLayout details;

    public AdminProjectsListViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        details = view.findViewById(R.id.details);
        tv_title = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        tv_priority = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_priority);
        tv_date = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
        tv_task = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_task);
        tv_time = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
        tv_assign = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_assign);
        tv_client = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_client);
        iv_status = view.findViewById(R.id.iv_status);

    }
}
}
```

logcat

```
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x12
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
    at bd.com.rtchubs.taskapp.admin_adapter.AdminProjectsListAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(AdminProjectsListAdapter.java:34)
    at bd.com.rtchubs.taskapp.admin_adapter.AdminProjectsListAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(AdminProjectsListAdapter.java:19)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6794)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5975)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18010)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18010)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18010)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18010)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18010)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18010)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18010)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18010)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3175)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18010)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2776)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2477)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1544)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7607)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
    at android.view.Choreographer.do
```

Comment: Can you try removing : `comment_background` from the `CardView` background and see what happens? However, you used too many `RelativeLayout`s, this is not a good choice-practice.

Comment: it not worked still getting same error and thanks for suggestion.@Mohsen

Comment: Can you please share the line number because it is not feasible to track line number 34 from your XML and parallelly the issue is direct with the dimensions. Please check your dimensions and values which you have used in the above layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `TextView` with id `tv_title` code

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@+id/iv_status"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="@string/btn_login"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Here you have used `android:layout_marginLeft="@+id/iv_status"`. `layout_marginLeft` accepts only dimension value. but you are passing id of view. Use a valid dimension value